# ArcGIS Pro dynamic text from attribute table in layout. Get first value

Tags: arcgis-pro, layouts, dynamic-text

I have feature class with many objects in extent and I need to add dynamic text to layout with only one value from Text field. All object in current extent has same field value.

Has anyone figure out how to do it?

Tag in text element

"<"dyn type="table" property="value" mapFrame="Фрейм карты" mapMemberUri="CIMPATH=__________/______2.xml" isDynamic="true" field="LH_mery.Lesnich" delimiter=" "/> –

What i have
[image]
[image]

What i need

[image]

Comment: Is this for screen display, outputting to. PDF, sharing as a map service or something else

Comment: What text and tag is in your current text element?

Comment: <dyn type="table" property="value" mapFrame="Фрейм карты" mapMemberUri="CIMPATH=__________/______2.xml" isDynamic="true" field="LH_mery.Lesnich" delimiter=" "/>

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

If the text is the same for every feature in your dataset, then you could set it by using a "custom query" where you set your query to select a single `ObjectID`.
So, insert table attribute, under "Source" and "Query" select custom query, and enter as your query `"OBJECTID = 1"`. That way only a single value will appear.